# Tablespace Creation and Reassignment

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, sqlplus, scripting

> It has been determined that user "SCOTT" should use a new temporary
>   tablespace called TEMP2 size equivalent to TEMP tablespace (refer to
>   Notes below for determining the size of TEMP).   Create a script that
>   performs the following
>
> Create one Bigfile tablespace for TEMP2.  size equal to the size of
>   TEMP Change the default temporary tablespace for "SCOTT" to TEMP2

This is what I have come up with so far, I have used a combination of the Oracle 11g DBA Handbook, also the Oracle website knowlege base at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tspaces.htm#ADMIN011
for example.

I cannot find how to determine the size of "TEMP". I have been able to locate the temp tablespace though. I just havent figured out the query to find out the size.

what I have so far is:

```
create bigfile tablespace TEMP2
    datafile '/u06/oradata/TEMP2.dbf' size ?g;

alter user SCOTT temporary tablespace TEMP2;
```

any help or insight would be appreciated, the script is for 11g and SQL Plus. Thanks, I am a newb.

Comment: I am having trouble with; Verify the temporary table space for user "SCOTT" by performing query on "user_users" table. 
Determine details of the temporary tablespace by performing query on "user_tablespaces". also.

Comment: so using the above answer I found the size of the TEMP file. Now I want to create another temporary file called TEMP2 that is the same size. what I entered was;

create bigfile tablespace TEMP2
    tempfile '/u01/oradata/TEMP2.dbf' size 2048m
    autoextend off extent management local uniform size 512k;

and was told I had insufficient privileges. So now I am working on figuring out the priveleges. gheeze

Comment: Login as sysdba. "connect / as sysdba" in SQLPlus. If you're using SQL Developer, login as SYS and check the "as SYSDBA" box

Comment: yeah for some reason it wont let me log in as anything other than sysman or scott. So since I am using virtual box I am gonna dump it and reload a new one and try to figure it out. I submitted the assignment already.

Comment: Thanks @Phil, I didnt understand how to log in "connect / as sysdba" at the time. I did figure it out and appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the size of `TEMP`, in bytes (obviously divide by a few 1024s to get Gigabytes):

```
select sum(bytes)
from dba_temp_files
where tablespace_name = 'TEMP';
```

Doc link for the view [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4158.htm#REFRN23288).

Answer (score 1):

Below will show temp file size in megabytes

```
select sum(bytes)/1024/1024 as sizemb,tablespace_name 
from dba_temp_files order by tablespace_name;
```

Comment: thanks, I have finally figured out the deal with my instructor and this class. I have learned so much but feel like this forum is not the place to pose questions and learn the answers or figure things out. Too much attitude or distaste for newbs I think. Appreciate your response though. I am not sure how to mark this question as answered though.